# How to find out "Problems in this file" errors in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

In my project, I have a file that has turned red and it says it has 8 errors. How do I find these errors?

I'm attaching my screenshots below:

[image: red file name]

[image: error markers]

Comment: Go to the `Problems` pane - part of the same panel as the Terminal.

Comment: Thank you, sir. You beauty!

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Bit late to the punch, however you can use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, which will open the problems pane.

Comment: `cmd` + `shift` + `M` for mac

Answer (score 20):

You can use this command:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

By the way, you can quickly jump to errors and warnings in the project.

Cycle through errors with:

<kbd>F8</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>

You can filter problems either by type ('errors', 'warnings') or text matching with the above search bar you'll see.

Another useful filter is 'Show Active File Only'

Reference [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks)

Comment: using 'Show Active File Only' filter is what I find most helpful...
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_41.md#problems-panel

Comment: No need to have the problem pane shown - straight to F8 - quick, brilliant, and space saving.