# compiling js failed react native expected buffer size

Tags: react-native

My code was working fine and then suddenly start showing error something like this:-

Compiling JS failed: 180820:25:';' expected Buffer size 7070676 starts with:....... and has protection mode(s): r--p

**Error Screenshot**
[image: Error Screenshot]

I tried resetting the cache with

```
npx react-native start --reset-cache
```

I am using the latest version of every module in my code the last change is to remove the "AsyncStorage" module.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

After reviewing the change I made, it  seems that I used and await call outside an async function, and that's what caused this error.

Comment: Very helpful, thankt! 

A note: You can view your bundle at http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true. - Copy-Paste it to an IDE and you'll see what went wrong

Comment: @LukasHechenberger can you explain what you mean by this, I did this and found a function definition at the line number and this belongs to a dependency

Comment: Well it very much depends on what kind of error you're experiencing, but after visiting this URL you should at least have a valid error location, so you can retrace what went wrong - I can't tell what went wrong in your case without the error message and the jsbundle contents

Comment: @LukasHechenberger amazing tip. My issue was a missing comma at a JSON file I use for i18n and would be very hard to find otherwise.

Comment: Same as @ekrembk... my issue was a missing comma in my JSON file

Answer (score 10):

I experienced the same issue due to a missing curly bracket in one of my translation (localization) files. Resolving this by fixing the file resolved the issue.

Answer (score 7):

I'll just emphasize the comment [@Lukas Hechenberger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3880353/lukas-hechenberger) made on the selected answer: *"You can view your bundle at localhost:8081/…. - Copy-Paste it to an IDE and you'll see what went wrong"*.

This link was a life saver, as it indicates clearly at which line the problem happened - be it an invalid JSON or a misplaced `await`.

The link is:

```
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true
```

replacing the `platform` part with your needs, `ios` or `android`.

Comment: how can I use this to find the error? I just get the app bundle code of thousand of lines

Comment: Somewhere in your error message there should be the line and column of your error.

In case of the op's screenshot, it was on line 180820, column 25

Comment: @JohhanSantana you'll need to copy the contents of the bundled code into a new file in a code editor, like VS Code. Once VS Code processes and lints the contents of the file, it should indicate where the error is. I found the error by doing ctrl+shift+m from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59893036/2524730

Answer (score 3):

try ***npm cache clean --force*** or  ***yarn cache clean***

Answer (score 3):

```bash
find . -name "*.json" -not -path "./node_modules/*" -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' -r filename; do
    if ! jq . "$filename" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "$filename is invalid"
    fi
done
```

This bash script may help to find some `.json` files malformed. Which leads to this crash.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem until I realized that I had imported and used a `json` file, but it was empty.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issue due to a missing Quotation mark ("), just run react-native bundle command and it will show you the error line

*react-native bundle --dev false --platform android --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ./android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/src/main/res*

Answer (score 1):

Having the exact same issue, using typescript react native, get this issue when runs the application in android emulator, problem happens when creating the axios instance inside of service.ts file.

```
[Error: Exception in HostFunction: Compiling JS failed: 4:3:export declaration must be at top level of module Buffer size 1287 starts with: 5f5f642866756e6374696f6e2028676c]
```

import axios from "axios"

var instance = axios.create

```
"axios": "1.1.0",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.73.1",
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After spending two days attempting various solutions, including clearing the cache, restarting, creating a new emulator, validating asynchronous operations without synchronization, and checking JSON files for errors, none of them resolved the issue.

Ultimately, clearing the temporary files on Windows using '%Temp%' proved to be the solution, and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue due to a syntax problem in the used translation json files of I18N module.
Just fixing the syntax problem of translation files resolved the probem.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue in my development setup. To resolve it, I completely removed my existing virtual device and then set up a new one from scratch. This process effectively addressed the problem within my Android development environment on a Windows 11 system.

Here are the steps I followed for anyone facing a similar issue

1. Open the Android Virtual Device (AVD) Manager in your Android development environment.
2. Select the problematic virtual device and click on the "Delete" option to remove it.
3. After successfully deleting the old virtual device, click on the "Create Virtual Device" button to initiate the setup of a new device.
4. Follow the on-screen instructions to configure your new virtual device according to your development needs.

This method worked for me and might be beneficial for others experiencing similar issues."

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue, and I wasn't using any async function.

I simply uninstalled the app and rebuilt it, and the app started working.

Answer (score -3):

Use .then instead of await in your application