# "Compiling JS failed" in React Native

Tags: react-native, mobile, android-emulator

I am trying to solve the below error in my React Native application.

Some people reported getting a similar error when they use asynchronous calls incorrectly. 
However, I tried rewriting all my asynchronous code to promises and even commenting it all out, but I still get the error.

[image]

Comment: Does this also happen when using a fresh React Native template/installation?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you narrow down what screen or function causes the error? Without seeing any code it's hard to give any suggestions.

Comment: As noted in [this answer comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72115193/7581249): _You can view your bundle at http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true - Copy-Paste it to an IDE and you'll see what went wrong_

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild, Run Yarn IOS again Or Yarn Android Again